# Как исправить Warning: Creating default object from empty value in

Tags: php7.4

Как исправить Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /www/wwwroot/***/scripts/functions.php on line 760

Код:

```
$zapros_channel="";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data->items[$i] = new stdClass();
    $id=$row['youtube_id'];
    $data->items[$i]->id=$row['ID'];
    $data->items[$i]->youtube_id=$row['youtube_id'];
    $data->items[$i]->title=$this->format_title($row['name']);
    $data->items[$i]->description=$row['description'];
    $data->items[$i]->datetime=$row['datetime'];
    $data->items[$i]->img_small=Main::http_to_https($row['img_small']);
    $data->items[$i]->img_medium=Main::http_to_https($row['img_medium']);
    $data->items[$i]->img_large=Main::http_to_https($row['img_large']);
    $data->items[$i]->channel_id=$row['channel_id'];
    $data->items[$i]->playlist_id=$row['playlist_id'];
    $data->items[$i]->quality=$row['quality'];
    $data->items[$i]->likes=$row['likes'];
    $data->items[$i]->comments=$row['comments'];
    $data->items[$i]->views=$row['views'];
    $data->items[$i]->dislikes=$row['dislikes'];
    $data->items[$i]->duration=$row['duration'];
    $data->items[$i]->deleted=$row['deleted'];
    $channel_id=$data->items[$i]->channel_id;
    if(!empty($row['description'])){
        $data->items[$i]->description=$row['description'];
    }
    if($i!=0){
        $zapros_channel.=" OR ";
    }
    $zapros_channel.="`channel_id`='$channel_id'";
    $i++;
}
```

}

Строка:

```
$data->items[$i] = new stdClass();
```

Как исправить?

Comment: что нахожится в data на момент цикла смотрел? $data->items вообще существует?

Comment: Не знаю как смотреть

Comment: Тогда читаем про отладку выше

Comment: В php 7.3 такой проблемы не было, переехал на новый сервер с php 7.4 появилась эта ошибка

Comment: Потому что стало строже по некоторым правилам. Подебажь, посмотри что на каждом этапе происходит. скорее всего одна из переменных пуста и надо это поправить

Comment: `var_export($data);` или `print_r($data);`перед строкой с ошибкой

Comment: Добавилось уведомление: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: data in <b>/www/wwwroot/***/scripts/functions.php</b> on line <b>760</b><br />

Comment: ну вот и ответ что не так

Comment: но ниже этого вылезло много массивов, сюда не проходит столько текста

Comment: `stdClass Object
(
[items] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 43238
[youtube_id] => aM0GDkzX3YI
[title] => МЕНЮ на День Рождения..
[description] => Меню на День..
[datetime] => 2020-08-28T14:00:00Z
[img_small] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aM0GDkzX3YI/default.jpg
[img_medium] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aM0GDkzX3YI/mqdefault.jpg
[img_large] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aM0GDkzX3YI/hqdefault.jpg
[channel_id] => UCo..
[playlist_id] => PL8..
[quality] => hd
[likes] => 41481
[comments] => 502
[views] => 1329747
[dislikes] => 825
[duration] => PT18M48S
[deleted] => 0
)
)
)`

Comment: Я так и не понял, где ответ?)