# Не работает реврайт

Tags: nginx

Перенес сайт на новый сервер с другой панелью управления (aaPanel) перенес конфиг сайта nginx, все работает кроме одного rewrite, что можете посоветовать?

Код:

```
location / {
    location /image {
      rewrite ^/image/(.+).jpg$ /static/image.php?id=$1 last;
    }
}
```

По этому адресу изображение есть:

```
https://mydomain.com/static/image.php?id=AtYOA6MXJ6U
```

А тут 404:

```
https://mydomain.com/image/AtYOA6MXJ6U.jpg
```

Как исправить?

Comment: 404 от nginx или от php? Что в логах ошибок написано?

Comment: 2022/06/16 00:09:00 [error] 346168#346168: *126680 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /www/wwwroot/mydomain.com/scripts/functions.php on line 760PHP message: PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /www/wwwroot/mydomain.com/scripts/functions.php on line 855PHP message: PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /www/wwwroot/mydomain.com/scripts/functions.php on line 760",

Comment: Но я не уверен что эти ошибки относятся к выводу того изображения, после переезда на другой сервер, вылазят ошибки и не реврайтит изображение, вот тут уже писал про php ошибки (но пока решения нет): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/Как-исправить-warning-creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in

Comment: А в логах ошибок nginx что?

Comment: В логах ничего нет, если выношу строку rewrite ^/image/(.+).jpg$ /static/image.php?id=$1 last; с location / то все работает, не понятно по чему остальные реврайты работают корректно в нутри location / а именно этот не работает, срабатывает только если его выношу с location /

Answer (score 1):

Поищите среди других location регулярку, под которую попадает ваш запрос /image/AtYOA6MXJ6U.jpg. Например `location ~* \.jpg$`

**Дело в порядке обработки локейшанов. Ваш `location /image` будет обработан после:**

1. location = /image/AtYOA6MXJ6U.jpg
2. location ^~ /image
3. location ~* .jpg$

Чтобы увидеть весь конфиг дайте команду `nginx -T`

Comment: Отобразил весь конфиг, залил его в текстовый документ, прошелся поиском .jpg$ и нашел только тот реврайт который вынес за пределы локейшен, днугих нет.

Comment: я привел регулярку для примера, вариантов может быть много и все они отработают перед. Приложили бы свой конфиг

Comment: Выложил конфиг по ссылке:
https://privnote.com/HIPcXnAp#4CC7JoAGS

Comment: вот же отрабатывающий локейшн     location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$

Comment: Из-за него мой rewrite не отрабатывает внутри другого location, а работает только когда вне location?

Comment: да. Для каждого запроса будет выбран только один location в порядке приоритета, указанного мной